# Migracion a Gx17 U5 - Cambia URL imagenes

Tags: genexus

Tenemos una aplicacion desarrollada con Gx16 U11 y la estamos migrando a Gx17 U5
Las kbs (tanto la original como la migrada) fueron creadas en español y tiene la propiedad Translation Type = Run-time

Los objetos imágenes estas definidos con la propiedad language = Any.

Nos sucede que en la aplicación migrada muchas de las imágenes no se ven.
Inspeccionamos el html y encontramos que las url se estan armando distinto.

Tomo como ejemplo la imagen de fondo de la pantalla de login

En la aplicación original, la url toma la imagen de resources

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la aplicacion migrada va a buscar la imagen a la carpeta Resoruces/spanish

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que arma la url distintas siendo que las aplicaciones se corren en la mismas condiciones.

En ambas kbs la imagen esta definida igual language (any)
Una situación similar nos ocurre con algunas imágenes que va a buscar a la carpeta del tema

Hay alguna propiedad que se deba setear en la nueva versión para compatibilizar este comportamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Ese no es el comportamiento esperado. Parece ser un problema para reportar a soporte. Un posible arreglo seria copiar a mano las imagenes que estas perdiendo, a las rutas donde las esta yendo a buscar... al menos hasta que se solucione el problema en futuros upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

He estado trabajando con Gx16U11 y pase a Gx17U8 hace poco.
Gx17 cambio la forma de leer y generar las URLs, por lo que tuve un problema parecido al tuyo: mi aplicación no encontraba la imagen, ya que estaba buscándola en otro directorio.
Lo solucione al darme cuenta que para direccionar la imagen estaba usando la siguiente forma "../imagen.jpg" y tuve que cambiarla a "./imagen.jpg".

Espero que esto te sirva, al menos, de punta para encontrar la solución.